# Is there a way to intercept queries about library meta data?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Okay, so i've put `c#` and `cpp` in the tags, but really this relates to any language. And it's not windows specific either.

Say i have a web api, which has a function which will return all of the possible queries in some interface description language (doesn't matter which one).

Now say i have a library that at runtime does some magic stuff inside and grabs all the functions from the api idl call and injects these functions into itself.

This is nice, but i don't get any code completion in ides, since it only happens at runtime.

**Is there a way to intercept the queries about the dll's meta data and replace the result with something generated from the api idl call?**

I plan on doing this in .net, but am curious about solution in other languages too.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a reference to a web service in Visual Studio, you get code completion - but possibly you are not using Visual Studio or the web service is not compatible.

I don't think you will solve any issue intercepting the metadata calls - you mention that the library fetches the metadata at runtime, which is too late so you will also intercept these queries too late.

Similar to how Visual Studio tackles this, you could write a converter yourself that downloads metadata and generates code. After running the converter, your code can compile against the generated code, while under the hood the generated code makes the actual web service calls.

Whenever the service contract changes, you can run the converter again, and your code will show errors where the contract has changed.

Comment: I realised i could do this - this does not solve the issue of the code going out of date if i add functions to the api. What i mean, is when you query the members of a dll, does that call something inside the dll in any way? or does it just look up the members in some index of the dll? Is there a way to create something that looks like a dll which, when something else goes digging into it's /index/, if that's what it is, it instead goes online to my api and downloads the latest api and then generates all that's needed in the /index/ to send back out to whatever was querying it?

Comment: A web service can _choose_ to export its metadata, and the web service can _choose_ to generate it differently for each separate request. A dll contains metadata which can be read by any application. No code of the dll is executed while its metadata is being read. The dll will never contain different metadata than the last time you checked. I've got the feeling I'm not completely understanding where you're going.

Comment: Nono, it sounds like you know exactly what I'm saying from that - and that's the was I presumed it worked. I was hoping there was a way around it.  Are you positive there's no way to make the Metadata of a "dll" point to something that actually fetches it from somewhere, via some magic incantation of (probably utterly not cross pkatform) horrivle/amazing magic? That's what I'm interested in understanding, mainly out of curiosity now! I'm never going to do this, as I imagine it would be a maintenance nightmare.